# Sprint work item default value

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I need to set a default value for the Retrospective tab in TFS 2015.

Factory value is the following (TEXT 1):

```
What worked?

What didn't work?

What will we do differently?
```

Using the Powertools, I add a DEFAULT rule. In the rule i specify the following default value for the Retrospective (TEXT 2):

```
What worked?
Please check out what you wanted to do differently in the last two sprints.

What didn't work?

What will we do differently?
```

So really it's just adding `Please check out what you wanted to do differently in the last two sprints.`

Now here comes the problem. I save my work, and if I create a sprint in Visual Studio, TEXT 2 is displayed.

If I create a Sprint in Online TFS (accessed from browser), it will show TEXT 1.

Did anyone have a similar problem in the past?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Why don't you overwrite the factory default? I have experienced a similar issue myself. I believe the rules you apply in a WITD file are not always consistently evaluated in both VS and Web Access. Note that the whole WITD seem to become deprecated in the not so distant future since Microsoft is allowing customizations directly from WebAccess in Team Services already. So it is quite possible that Web Access does not implement the WITD 100% as does. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/vsts-process-customization-futures-january-2016/

Comment: TFS 2015 doesn't have Sprint work item, did you customize it?

Answer (score 0):

The Sprint work item, used in TFS 2010 with the MS Scrum 1.0 process template, was removed from the Scrum process template 2.0 of TFS 2012.

However since TFS 2012, you configure the sprint schedule as part of the new Agile Planning feature, making the Sprint work item redundant.

So your options for storing the goals\retrospective:

- Use a Task work item (Title, Description fields)
- Add custom field in the Product Backlog Item
- Use SharePoint integration - store as a document